# How to provide a simple download section with sub folders in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to provide a simple download section via Django that lists files and sub folders and allows for downloading. I am using pythonanywhere for this.

Here is my Link with the error: https://futureforest.eu.pythonanywhere.com/download/

Application name: servedownload

views.py in servedownload:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
from django.http import FileResponse, Http404

def download_folder(request, path=''):
    # Set the file path to the directory you want to serve for download
    folder_path = os.path.join('/home/futureforest/webinterface/media/download', path)

    # Check if the folder exists, and raise a 404 error if it doesn't
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        raise Http404('Folder not found')

    # Get a list of all the files and directories in the folder
    contents = os.listdir(folder_path)

    # Create empty lists for files and subdirectories
    files = []
    subdirectories = []

    # Iterate through the contents of the folder
    for item in contents:
        item_path = os.path.join(folder_path, item)

        # If the item is a file, add it to the list of files
        if os.path.isfile(item_path):
            files.append(item)

        # If the item is a directory, add it to the list of subdirectories
        elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
            subdirectories.append(item)

    # Recursively retrieve files from subdirectories
    subfiles = []
    for subdirectory in subdirectories:
        subfiles.extend(download_folder(request, os.path.join(path, subdirectory)))

    # Combine the files in the current directory with the files in the subdirectories
    files.extend(subfiles)

    # Render the template with the list of files and subdirectories
    return render(request, 'download_folder.html', {'path': path, 'files': files, 'subdirectories': subdirectories})

def download_file(request, path, filename):
    # Set the file path to the directory you want to serve for download
    folder_path = '/home/futureforest/webinterface/media/download'

    # Build the full file path
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, path, filename)

    # Check if the file exists, and raise a 404 error if it doesn't
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        raise Http404('File not found')

    # Check if the file path is actually a directory, and raise a 404 error if it is
    if os.path.isdir(file_path):
        raise Http404('Not a file')

    # Serve the file as a downloadable response
    response = FileResponse(open(file_path, 'rb'), as_attachment=True)
    return response
```

In servedownload/templates I have a download_folder.html and download_file.html:
download_folder.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download folder contents</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Download folder contents:</h1>
    {% if path %}
        <p>Current path: {{ path }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <ul>
        {% for subdirectory in subdirectories %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'download_folder' path=request.path|urlencode|add:'/'|add:subdirectory %}">{{ subdirectory }}/</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for file in files %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'download_file' path=path|add:'/'|urlencode filename=file %}">{{ file }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and download_file.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Download file:</h1>
    {% if path %}
        <p>Current path: {{ path }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <p>File: {{ filename }}</p>
    <a href="{{ file_url }}" download>Download file</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the project url.py, I have added following paths:

```
path('download/', servedownload.download_folder, name='download_folder'),
path('download/<path:path>/', servedownload.download_folder, name='download_folder'),
path('download/<str:filename>/', servedownload.download_file, name='download_file'),
path('download/<path:path>/<str:filename>/', servedownload.download_file, name='download_file'),
```

Comment: And how it is failing?  Do you get any errors (for example in the error log)?